# How to implement IDbContextFactory for use with Entity Framework data migrations

Tags: entity-framework, data-migration

I am trying to use Entity Framework data migrations, as described in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx).

However, when I try to execute the `Enable-Migrations` step, I receive the following error in Package Manager Console:

```
The target context 'MyDataContext' is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory
```

So, I created a factory class that implements `IDbContextFactory` in the project that contains my `DbContext` class, but data migrations doesn't appear to recognize it.

Is there something that I should explicitly do to instruct data migrations to use this factory class?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I also hit this problem as i wrote my context to take a connection string name (and then used ninject to provide it).

The process you've gone through seems correct, here is a snippet of my class implementation if it's of any help:

```
public class MigrationsContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDBContext("connectionStringName");
    }
}
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it works. I can't imagine what I did wrong first time around, as I recall implementing exactly the same pattern myself. In any case, problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put this class?

Comment: I would suggest putting it in an assembly which contains your 'MyContext' class. I would typically keep such a class in a separate assembly such as MyApp.Data.Model or MyApp.Domain.Model, something along those lines.

Comment: Could you please provide the Ninject configuration code?  I don't understand where I would inject the connectionStringName as Create does not take a constructor parameter.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald - Any reason, why we cannot inject the context into the ContextFactory and return that instead of new'ing a DbContext instance in the create method of the ContextFactory class?

Comment: How does EF know about the presence of the factory class - MigrationsContextFactory. Don't we have to register it somewhere so that the framework would know? Is having this class lie independently self-sufficient ? Tim also seems to have acknowledged that it won't be required!

Comment: @Legolas21 I know this is old, but just FYI, I've found that EF will automatically detect any classes inheriting the interface `IDbContextFactory<>`, according to [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506876(v=vs.113).aspx). I believe this is still true for .NET Core.

Comment: FYI [IDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.idbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-2.1) is now obsolete. use [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-2.1) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Soren pointed out, instead of using `IDbContextFactory`, not supported on some earlier **EF Core** releases (i.e. EF Core 2.1), we can implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>`, which supports the missing **ConnectionString** parameter.

For a **settings.json** based aproach, which you can use with either of the referred interfaces, check [@Arayn's sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418717/378115) which allows us to define "**ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection**" value path

**Update 1**

According to @PaulWaldman's comment, on **EF Core 5** support for `IDbContextFactory` was reintroduced. For further details, check his comment below.

Comment: It's better to mark an answer as duplicate than just linking to it.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold. I am not sure what you meant. It seems that you are suggesting that I did something wrong (which I may), but I can't figure it out. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You link to an existing SO answer. It's usually better to (flag to) close the current question as duplicate of the answer you link to.

Comment: Actually, I've never flagged one, but I will take your advice from now on. However, in this particular question, I will not, since either the question targets a different EF interface. Anyway, thanks for poiting it out

Comment: IDbContextFactory is no longer obsolete.  It was reintroduced in EF Core 5.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor