# Instantiate DbContext-derived class with Mehdime.Entity AmbientDbContextLocator

Tags: ef-code-first, ninject, mehdime-entity

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am wanting to use `Mehdime.Entity` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mehdime.Entity in order to manage my DBContext-derived classes in a Console Application.  I am also using NInject.

The connection strings for my DBContext-derived classes are partially generated from standard app.config ConnectionStrings and also by an AppDomain value that (in my Console App case) comes in via a command line argument.

My DBContext-derived classes have their connection strings prepared using a program-implemented class which takes into account of the command line argument as follows:

```
public class TaskManagementDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TaskManagementDbContext(IConnectionStringResolver csr) :
        base(csr.GetConnectionString("Default"))
    {
    }
}
```

(`IConnectionStringResolver` basically implements `GetConnectionString()` which returns the connection string by using given named standard app.config ConnectionString and the command line argument.

This is fine when I use NInject to instantiate the DbContext directly but when trying to use with `Mehdime.Entity`, it is `AmbientDbContextLocator` that is doing the instantiation and it throws a `MissingMethodException` because it requires my DBContext-derived class to have a parameterless constructor:

```
public class TaskRepository : ITaskRepository
{
    private readonly IAmbientDbContextLocator _ambientDbContextLocator;

    private TaskManagementDbContext DbContext
    {
        get
        {
            // MissingMethodException thrown "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"
            var dbContext = _ambientDbContextLocator.Get<TaskManagementDbContext>();
            ...
        }
    }
```

How should I provide a connection string to my DBContext-derived classes at run-time in this situation?  I suspect I am going about this the wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: Further searching has uncovered the following which will probably lead to an answer for me: 

(1) [How to implement IDbContextFactory for use with Entity Framework data migrations](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/540033/IDbContextFactory-which-gets-Connection-String-at), (2)

[github DbContextScope Issue #8](https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope/issues/8), 

(3) [How to implement IDbContextFactory for use with Entity Framework data migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395283/how-to-implement-idbcontextfactory-for-use-with-entity-framework-data-migrations)

Answer (score 2):

OK. I've worked out the solution and I'm putting it here for anyone else with this issue:

1. Create your own implementation of `IDbContextFactory` (see below).  I put this in the same class library as my Data Access Layer (i.e. my DbContexts).  You will see in my example how I "look for" a specific constructor prototype (in my case, 1 parameter of type `IDbContextFactory` - your's will no doubt be different).  If found, get the actual parameters and invoke a new instance of your DBContext-derived class.  If not found, you can throw an exception or in my case, try to call the default constructor (if exists).

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Mehdime.Entity;
using Ninject;
using TaskProcessor.Common;

namespace TaskProcessor.Data.Connection
{
    public class DbContextWithCSRFactory : IDbContextFactory
    {
        public TDbContext CreateDbContext<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : DbContext
        {
            // Try to locate a constuctor with a single IConnectionStringResolver parameter...
            var ci = typeof(TDbContext).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IConnectionStringResolver) });
            if(ci != null)
            {
                // Call it with the actual parameter
                var param1 = GlobalKernel.Instance.Get<IConnectionStringResolver>();
                return (TDbContext)ci.Invoke(new object[] { param1 });
            }

            // Call parameterless constuctor instead (this is the default of what DbContextScope does)
            return (TDbContext)Activator.CreateInstance<TDbContext>();
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create a binding in NInject so that your  `IDbContextFactory` implementation is called:

Code:

```
private void AddBindings(IKernel kernel)
{   ...
    kernel.Bind<IDbContextFactory>().To<Data.Connection.DbContextWithCSRFactory>().InSingletonScope();
}
```

Everything now falls into place.