# Provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory. But where?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to run migrations with custom DbContext.

```
var migrationConfiguration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration { AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true };
migrationConfiguration.ContextType = typeof(DataContext);
var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationConfiguration);
migrator.Update();
```

This throws Migration Exception, because `DataContext`does not implement parameterless constructor:

> The target context 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory.

The `DataContext`constructor requires parameters, but I already have `IDbContextFactory<DataContext>` created. How do I tell DbMigrator, to use existing implementation of `IDbContextFactory<DataContext>`?

Comment: Something else is wrong here - note the `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` (not `DataContext`) in the exception message.

Comment: Show your context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395283/how-to-implement-idbcontextfactory-for-use-with-entity-framework-data-migrations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IDbContextFactory<>` has be in same assembly and provide **parameterless** constructor.

Another way is to inherit DbConfiguration and set factory in **parameterless** constructor of derived class (I'm using MEF to get class derived from IDbContextFactory):

```
public class DataContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public DataContextConfiguration()
    {
        SetContextFactory(() => (DataContext)new CompositionManager().Container.GetExportedValue<IDataContextFactory>().Create());
    }
}
```

Comment: Lack of parameterless constructor was my issue, adding it in solved it.