# Why does a hosted service need its dependent services to be AddScoped()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, background-task, asp.net-core-hosted-services

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task):

> To use scoped services within a BackgroundService, create a scope. No scope is created for a hosted service by default.

That's fine, and it's what the example code does:

```
using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
{
    var scopedProcessingService = 
        scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

    await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
}
```

But then when the `IScopedProcessingService` service is registered in `IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices` *(Program.cs)*, it is added with `AddScoped`:

```
    services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, ScopedProcessingService>();
```

Is this necessary? According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#service-lifetimes), `AddScoped()` scopes the `ScopedProcessingService` to the lifetime of the Http Request. However, this is a background service, and so there is no Http Request. If I change the code to use `AddTransient()` instead, it runs fine:

```
    services.AddTransient<IScopedProcessingService, ScopedProcessingService>();
```

Is `AddScoped()` necessary or just a performance optimisation in case some code that is running inside a Http Request (eg, a Controller) tries to resolve a `IScopedProcessingService` service?

Comment: Assuming you understand difference between 3 "lifetimes" (scoped, transient, singleton) it should not be a problem to decide which one to pick... Clearly in you case with a single resolution over the program's lifetime it absolutely does not matter which one to pick...

Comment: `AddScoped()` is mainly used in the context of HTTP Requests in asp.net. During the lifetime of a request, only one instance of the scoped class will be created.

Comment: "AddScoped() scopes the ScopedProcessingService to the lifetime of the Http Request" Well yes, but actually no. The kestrel web server creates a scope per request. But you can create scopes for any other reason. You'd create a scoped service like the example, so that your scoped service will be disposed when the `using var scope = ` variables is disposed.

Comment: Check these answers [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020799/net-core-dependency-injection-to-hosted-service) [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368634/how-should-i-inject-a-dbcontext-instance-into-an-ihostedservice/48368934#48368934)