# Cannot consume scoped service from singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use DBContext in Hosted services but getting this error.
I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368634/how-should-i-inject-a-dbcontext-instance-into-an-ihostedservice)  accepted answer but somehow its not working, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm new to .net please guide me into right direction.

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume
>   scoped service 'StatusApp.Context.DBContext' from singleton
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostedServiceExecutor'.

```
public class TokenService : IHostedService
{
    public IConfiguration _Configuration { get; }
    protected IMemoryCache _cache;
    private Timer _timer;
    public IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    public DBContext _DBcontext;

    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public TokenService(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, DBContext DBcontext, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _Configuration = configuration;
        _cache = memoryCache;
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _DBcontext = _scopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBcontext>();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(getOrg, null, 0, 1000);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Timer does not have a stop. 
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task getOrg()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "organizations");
        var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject>(json);

        foreach (var item in model.resources)
        {
            var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
            var x = _DBcontext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrgGuid == g);
            if (x == null)
            {
                _DBcontext.Organizations.Add(new Organizations
                {
                    OrgGuid = g,
                    Name = item.name,
                    CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                    UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                    Foundation = 3
                });
            }
            else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
            {
                x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're almost there, but you've left `DBContext` as a dependency in `TokenService`'s constructor. Remove that and you'll no longer receive the error.

```
public TokenService(
    IConfiguration configuration,
    IMemoryCache memoryCache,
    IHttpClientFactory clientFactory,
    DBContext DBcontext,
    IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
```

However, you're not quite following the recommendation for dealing with `DbContext`'s in a singleton service. Instead of creating a single instance of `DBContext` in the constructor and storing it as a field, create a scope and a corresponding `DBContext` whenever you need it. In your case, that's in the `getOrg` method.

Follow these steps to achieve that:

1. Remove the `_DBcontext` field from your `TokenService` class:

   ```
   public DBContext _DBcontext;
   ```
2. Remove the associated assignment from the `TokenService` constructor:

   ```
   _DBcontext = _scopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBcontext>();
   ```
3. In `getOrg`, create a scope, resolve an instance of `DBContext` and, lastly, dispose of the scope:

   ```
   public async Task getOrg()
   {
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "organizations");
       var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
       var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject>(json);

       using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
       {
           var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBcontext>();

           foreach (var item in model.resources)
           {
               var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
               var x = dbContext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrgGuid == g);
               if (x == null)
               {
                   dbContext.Organizations.Add(new Organizations
                   {
                       OrgGuid = g,
                       Name = item.name,
                       CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                       UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                       Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                       Foundation = 3
                   });
               }
               else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
               {
                   x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                   x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                   x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
               }
           }

           await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       }
   }
   ```

Instead of using the `_DBContext` field, the code above creates a local, properly-scoped variable `dbContext` and uses that instead.

Comment: I'm getting error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'TimerCallback'` in `StartAsync` function on `_timer` line, do you know by any chance whats wrong?

Comment: That's because the signature for the callback should be `void` but yours is `Task`. David Fowler has some awesome advice on handling this problem [here](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#timer-callbacks).