# Is it possible to include an argument in the IServiceScopeFactory.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceClass>()?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5, service-provider

Say I have the following code in the "HostedService" class using a IServiceScopeFactory to run a scope and create the service class instance (as explained here -> [How should I inject a DbContext instance into an IHostedService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368634/how-should-i-inject-a-dbcontext-instance-into-an-ihostedservice/48368934#48368934)):

```
using (var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{                                 
   var provisioningService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IProvisioningService>();
}
```

So, I'd like to do something akin as in the below code to include a parameter inside the instance service creation:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserCarrierService>(x => new UserCarrierService(user));
```

but this done using the IServiceScopeFactory class. If not, is it possible to override at all the once DI built in the Startup class at a later stage of the .net core program execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`IServiceScopeFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) does not allow passing overrides/additional dependencies when creating nested scopes. You need either use [3rd party container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement) which allows adding registrations to a lifetime scope like [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope) (also see [this](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html#example-singleton-lifetime)) or redesign your `IUserCarrierService` so it allows some kind of impersonation mechanism.