# How to use IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-2.1

I have ASP.NET Core 1.1 project, which I'm trying to convert to v2.1.

I've found `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementation, but I don't understand where I should create the instance of this factory and how to use it for migrations normal working. Now before create/remove migration I must clean and rebuild solution, because if not, I will get this message:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time

All context data is in separated project. How can I use the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementation or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add this class to folder where you have your DbContext.

```csharp
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
    {

        MyDbContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like the problem was in different projects and namespaces of MyDbContextFactory and MyDbContext

Comment: Nice!  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: According [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory), this class can be added to the startup project as well.

Comment: @derekbaker783 designtime builder is for design time purposes. startup registeration is for runtime.