# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - Azure Functions with .NET 5 (Isolated) Design-time DbContext Creation with HostBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework, .net-core

I have created a new `FunctionApp` in `Visual Studio Version 16.10.0` using the template `Azure Functions` with `.NET 5 (Isolated)` and `Http trigger`.

[image]

I have then created the following files:

Blog.cs

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(
                        connectionString,
                        sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(600)));
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Function1.cs

```
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

    public Function1(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1");
        logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var connectionString = _applicationDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FunctionApp1.Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that dependency injection works from `Program.cs` -> `new HostBuilder`

[image]

If I run `Add-Migration InitialCreate` in Package Manager Console I get the following error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the
> different patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=vs

To obtain the DbContext object from the application's service provider the example code looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

> The tools first try to obtain the service provider by invoking
> Program.CreateHostBuilder(), calling Build(), then accessing the
> Services property.

Is there anyway to make Tools work with HostBuilder instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a design time dbcontext, yes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Yes of course but passing a connection string between different environments becomes harder. If there was a way to integrate with `HostBuilder` I would prefer it. The solution below works good for Console Applications and similar but not Azure Functions using Environment Variables.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418717/3850405

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue for few days now. I just watched your solution and it helped me a lot. But I didn't create a StartUp class to add database context

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(service => ConfigureServices(service));
```

Inside `ConfigureServices` i just have :

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and it works.